# Auto-Rotation 19.04

Tags: display, 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my new Convertible Laptop and I have a problem.

It keeps Auto-rotating 90-degrees off, I can set it to normal with xrandr -o normal, but as soon as I log-off, turn-off or change the orientation of the Laptop, it changes back and goes to that orientation, but 90-degrees off.

I can't find an option to auto-disable auto-rotation, but if there would be one, I wouldn't use it, cause I need the orientation to be changeable, and not by terminal every time.

Can someone help me?